# Clean exit from X11 application?

Tags: c, linux, x11

This is a minimalistic linux application to bring up and close a window using X11.  I wanted a clean exit (as per valgrind) when the user presses ctrl-c in the terminal or clicks the "close" button on the windows manager.  It took a while to find this information so I thought I would post working code as well as ask a few questions.  I use signals to catch the "ctrl-c" and an Atom is used to catch the close button click.

Questions:
1)  Is this a proper/best way to accomplish a clean exit from an X11 app?
2)  Am I allowed to send an event in the signal handler code?  Some said no...
3)  Are there any other methods for catching windows manager events besides Atoms?

```
// use "gcc main.c -lX11" to compile
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>

// global data
struct { 
    Display* display;
    Window* window;
    char done;
} global;

void SignalHandler(int n) {
    switch(n) {
    case SIGINT:                    // user pressed ctrl-c from terminal
        global.done = 1;            // tell event loop to exit
        XClientMessageEvent event;  // dummy event to wake up XNextEvent
        memset(&event, 0, sizeof(XClientMessageEvent));
        event.type = ClientMessage;
        event.format = 32;          // not used but cannot be zero 
        XSendEvent(global.display, *global.window, 0, 0, (XEvent*)&event);
        XFlush(global.display);     // make event happen immediately
    }
}

void RegisterSignals() { signal(SIGINT, SignalHandler); }

int main () {

    memset(&global, 0, sizeof(global));
    RegisterSignals();

    Display* display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    global.display = display;

    Visual* visual = DefaultVisual(display, 0);
    int depth  = DefaultDepth(display, 0);

    XSetWindowAttributes frame_attr;
    frame_attr.background_pixel = XWhitePixel(display, 0);

    Window window = XCreateWindow(display, XRootWindow(display, 0),
        0, 0, 400, 300, 5, depth, InputOutput, visual, CWBackPixel, &frame_attr);
    global.window = &window;

    XStoreName(display, window, "Title");
    XSelectInput(display, window, 0xFFFF);

    XFontStruct* font = XLoadQueryFont(display, "10x20");
    XGCValues gc_values;
    gc_values.font = font->fid;
    gc_values.foreground = XBlackPixel(display, 0);
    GC gc = XCreateGC(display, window, GCFont + GCForeground, &gc_values);

    // Windows Manager Stuff (like clicking close button)
    Atom wmDeleteWindow = XInternAtom(display, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", True);
    XSetWMProtocols(display, window, &wmDeleteWindow, 1);

    XMapWindow(display, window);

    XEvent event;
    while (!global.done) {
        XNextEvent(display, (XEvent *)&event);  // blocks until event
        switch (event.type) {
            // other events go here...
            case ClientMessage:
            // user clicked close button on window
            if (event.xclient.data.l[0] == wmDeleteWindow) { global.done = 1; }
        }
    }

    // Cleanup
    XFreeGC(display, gc);
    XFreeFont(display, font);
    XCloseDisplay(display);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Because OP wants to? (for purposes of learning, maybe this is the start of a simplistic, custom framework, etc.)

Comment: Indeed, why not... But that is a very long journey...

Answer (score 3):

First, your signal handler is buggy. Read *carefully* [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) (notably the section on *async signal safe functions*) & POSIX [signal.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html) documentation. In practice, a signal handler should set some `volatile sig_atomic_t` flag to be tested elsewhere, so declare the `done`  field as `volatile sig_atomic_t done;` and have your signal handler just set that flag and do nothing more (in particular, move the `XSendEvent` outside of the signal handler). You could also be inspired by [Qt recommendations about Unix signals](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html) (e.g. use a `pipe` to self, `write` in it from the signal handler, and have an event loop around `poll` which could `read` that pipe and/or the X11 socket). But a signal handler *cannot* call (in a reliable way) `XSendEvent` which is *not* async signal safe. See also [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/).

Also, you want to follow the [EWMH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Window_Manager_Hints) conventions detailed [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html). This is complex and boring enough to practically justify using some *existing* X11 [toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits) like [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [GTK](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/) (or perhaps something else, like [libsdl](https://www.libsdl.org/), [libsfml](http://www.sfml-dev.org/index.php), [fox-toolkit](http://www.fox-toolkit.org/), [fltk](http://www.fltk.org/), ...). BTW, these toolkits (Qt & GTK at least) are probably transitioning to [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_%28display_server_protocol%29). To be provocative, X11 applications are becoming legacy, and are quite difficult to code right (*without* the support of some toolkit respecting X11 conventions such as EWMH).

BTW, these days, few applications are using the X11 core protocol and its drawing primitives (e.g. [XDrawLine](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/drawing/XDrawLine.html), [XDrawArc](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/drawing/XDrawArc.html), [XDrawText](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/drawing-text/XDrawText.html), ....). Most toolkits are drawing on the client side in client pixmaps (which is the model that Wayland is also using).

Coding an X11 application (conforming to EwMH) without toolkits is very difficult (will take you years; by the time you've done X11 could have been replaced by Wayland).

Comment: For the time being X11 is still better supported than Wayland and there are *lots* of interoperability issues left with Wayland. There are >30 years of rubber-hit-the-road experience in X11 which Wayland completely threw over board. For example input handling still is much more limited in Wayland, compared to XInput2 (which is a complex beast).

Comment: You are right, but coding an X11 application from scratch is *really* time consuming (if you want that to be right, e.g. EWMH conformant)

Comment: I will look into signals more.  Good info.  I can't move the XSendEvent() outside of the signal handler because XCloseDisplay() hangs (never returns) when XNextEvent() is blocking, thus it is impossible to cleanly exit (valgrind reports memory leaks).

Comment: No, you should code whatever is necessary to move `XSendEvent` *outsde* of the signal handler, and that is certainly possible.

Comment: @Dr.Wolfe: There's a trick on how to solve this "hanging": The so called "self-pipe-trick". X11 itself uses sockets for communication. Sockets have file descriptors and you can `select` or `poll` on file descriptors – multiple file descriptors at once, actually. So you can create an anonymous pipe with `pipe` and wait on the reading end of the pipe together with the X11 connection socket. In your signal handler you then can write a single byte to the pipe, which will release the block of `select` or `poll`; then check which fd has data and use XNextEvent the X11 fd has data.

Comment: @datenwolf: I mentioned that trick in my answer, before you wrote your comment :-)

Answer (score 2):

Version 2.  Works pretty well...  Thanks Basil and datenwolf for the advice.  Any comments would be great.

```
// Minimal X11 window with clean exit
// 1) "ctrl-c" from terminal or "kill -s SIGINT" exits app
// 2) user clicks close button to exit app
// Use -lX11 to comile with gcc

#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>

struct { 
    int pip[2];     // extra pipe for event loop
    sig_atomic_t done;  // flag to stop the event loop
} global;

void SignalHandler(int n) {
    write(global.pip[1], &global.done, 1);  // wake up select in X11 event loop
    switch(n) {
    case SIGINT:                // user pressed ctrl-c from terminal (or kill -s SIGINT)
        global.done = 1;            // tell event loop to exit
    }
}

void Initialize() { 
    struct sigaction sigact;        // no race conditions like signal()
    memset(&sigact, 0, sizeof(sigact));
    sigact.sa_handler = &SignalHandler;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sigact, NULL);
    memset(&global, 0, sizeof(global));
    pipe(global.pip);
    write(global.pip[1], &global.done, 1);  // wake up select on first iteration of X11 event loop
}

int main () {

    Initialize();

    Display* display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    int xfd = ConnectionNumber(display);

    Visual* visual = DefaultVisual(display, 0);
    int depth  = DefaultDepth(display, 0);

    XSetWindowAttributes frame_attr;
    frame_attr.background_pixel = XWhitePixel(display, 0);

    Window window = XCreateWindow(display, XRootWindow(display, 0),
        0, 0, 400, 300, 5, depth, InputOutput, visual, CWBackPixel, &frame_attr);

    XStoreName(display, window, "Title");
    XSelectInput(display, window, 0xFFFF);

    XFontStruct* font = XLoadQueryFont(display, "10x20");
    XGCValues gc_values;
    gc_values.font = font->fid;
    gc_values.foreground = XBlackPixel(display, 0);
    GC gc = XCreateGC(display, window, GCFont + GCForeground, &gc_values);

    // Windows Manager Stuff (like clicking close button)
    Atom wmDeleteWindow = XInternAtom(display, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", True);
    XSetWMProtocols(display, window, &wmDeleteWindow, 1);

    XMapWindow(display, window);

    fd_set set_read, set_save;
    FD_ZERO(&set_save); // select modifies fd_set, re-initialize
    FD_SET(xfd, &set_save);
    FD_SET(global.pip[0], &set_save);
    int max_fd = xfd > global.pip[0] ? xfd : global.pip[0];

    XEvent event;
    while (!global.done) {

        //printf("Blocking on select...\n");
        memcpy(&set_read, &set_save, sizeof(set_save));
        select(max_fd+1, &set_read, NULL, NULL, NULL);  // block on X11 and pipe

        if(!XPending(display)) {
            // this code only executes once on startup and once on exit
            char a[1]; read(global.pip[0], a, 1); continue; 
        }

        XNextEvent(display, (XEvent *)&event);  // doesn't block because we ensure an event
        //printf("Processing event...\n");
        switch ( event.type ) {
            // don't forget your other events...
            case ClientMessage:
            // user clicked close button on window
                if (event.xclient.data.l[0] == wmDeleteWindow) { global.done = 1; }
        }
    }

    //printf("Cleaning up...\n");
    close(global.pip[0]);
    close(global.pip[1]);
    XFreeGC(display, gc);
    XFreeFont(display, font);
    XCloseDisplay(display);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> 3) Are there any other methods for catching windows manager events
>   besides Atoms?

No. Atoms are used to 'register' these events (which are just strings in this case) and assign a number to them. This prevents a lot of hardcoded numbers and makes the system very flexible.